# My own metabox checkbox plugin only saves the last value I've checked

Tags: plugins, posts, metabox

I'm building my own metabox with checkboxes. I want to save the values of the checkboxes I've cheked as categories (IDs).

I have build an array to append the values of the checkboxes, but it only saves the last checkbox I have checked.

I'm trying to save the values using the following functions.

wp_set_post_categories();
wp_set_object_terms();

In addition, when I click the submit button for create / edit post, whatever the function I use, it  always saves the last value of checkbox.

Here is my code:

```
      add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_enhanced_categories_remove_meta_box');
function my_enhanced_categories_remove_meta_box(){
   remove_meta_box('categorydiv', 'post', 'normal');
}

//Add new taxonomy meta box
 add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_enhanced_categories_add_meta_box');
 function my_enhanced_categories_add_meta_box() {
     add_meta_box( 'category-all', 'Custom Portfolio Categories','my_enhanced_categories_category_metabox','post' ,'side','high');
 }


$postterms = get_the_terms( $post->ID,$taxonomy );

  function my_enhanced_categories_category_metabox( $post ) {

      //Set up the taxonomy object and get terms
$taxonomy = 'category';
$tax = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);//This is the taxonomy object

//The name of the form
$name = 'tax_input[' . $taxonomy . ']';

//Get all the terms for this taxonomy
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy,array('hide_empty' => 0));
     echo '<div id="' . $taxonomy . '-all" class="tabs-panel">';
     echo '<ul id="' . $taxonomy . '-checklist" class="list-' . $taxonomy . 'categorychecklist form-no-clear">';

     $categories = array();

     foreach($terms as $term){
            $id = $taxonomy.'-'.$term->term_id;

             echo "<li id='$id'><label>";

            echo "<input type='checkbox' id='in-$id' name='{$name}-$term->term_id' value='$term->term_id' />$term->name<br />";

            echo "</label></li>";

$key_tax = ($_POST['tax_input']);

if (!empty($key_tax)) {

array_push($categories, array_values($key_tax));




    /*wp_set_post_categories( $_POST['post_ID'], array_values($key_tax)[0]); */

}

        }?>

        </ul>
        </div>
        <?php



    }

//    var_dump($categories);
  //          wp_set_post_terms( $_POST['post_ID'], $categories, 'category' );

wp_set_object_terms( $_POST['post_ID'], $categories, 'category');
var_dump($categories);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly simple to achieve, first rename the `name` attribute to `my_categories[]` this is then passed as an array.

Then you will need set the `values` of each checkbox as the `category id`. In this way you can loop though the array `my_categories[]` and then set the categories present in that array.

**Here is a simplified example :**

```
// In your callback function for metabox,
// This should be inside a loop.
<input type="checkbox" name="my_categories[]" value="$term->term_id">


<?php 
// This should be hooked to the save_post action of appropriate post type.
if(!empty($_POST['my_categories'])) { 
    foreach($_POST['my_categories'] as $cat) 
        { 
            echo $cat; 
            //echoes the value set in the HTML form for each checked checkbox.
            //In your case the ids of selected checkboxes, now all you need to do is set those categories.
        } 
    } 
 ?>
```

Now you have all the ids of selected categories in an array, which is easier to process. Use your logic to set the categories.

Comment: Thanks @kabiir, the example solved my main question. 

Now, I'm trying to apply it to a custom content type, in my case "portfolio". This "portfolio" content type has "portfolio_categories", but when I remove his metabox and add my own metabox, doesn't apply the changes.

Comment: This is a different problem, ask another question.

Comment: Then post the link to that question in this comment and I'll look into it.

Comment: Thanks @kabiir http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256534/save-metabox-checkboxes-values-to-custom-content-type