# Save metabox checkboxes values to custom content type

Tags: categories, customization, metabox, content

I'm trying to save checkboxes values to categories for custom content type. I have printed the values of the IDs, the array with checkboxes values and all looks good, but at the end, the values doesn't save.

My custom content type is "portfolio", and his category "portfolio_categories".

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'enhanced_portfolio_categories_remove_meta_box');
function enhanced_portfolio_categories_remove_meta_box(){
   remove_meta_box('portfolio_categoriesdiv', 'portfolio', 'normal');
}

//Add new taxonomy meta box
 add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'enhanced_portfolio_categories_add_meta_box');
 function enhanced_portfolio_categories_add_meta_box() {
     add_meta_box( 'portfolio_categoriesdiv', 'My Custom Portfolio Categories','enhanced_portfolio_categories_category_metabox','portfolio' ,'side','high');
 }

  function enhanced_portfolio_categories_category_metabox( $post ) {

      //Set up the taxonomy object and get terms
$taxonomy = 'portfolio_categories';
$tax = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);//This is the taxonomy object

//The name of the form
$name = 'tax_input[' . $taxonomy . ']';

//Get all the terms for this taxonomy
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy,array('hide_empty' => 0));
     echo '<div id="' . $taxonomy . '-all" class="tabs-panel">';
     echo '<ul id="' . $taxonomy . '-checklist" class="list-' . $taxonomy . 'categorychecklist form-no-clear">';

     $categories = array();

     foreach($terms as $term){
            $id = $taxonomy.'-'.$term->term_id;

             echo "<li id='$id'><label>";

            echo "<input type='checkbox' id='in-$id' name='my_categories[]' value='$term->term_id' />$term->name<br />";

            echo "</label></li>";

        }?>

        </ul>
        </div>
        <?php



    }

//    var_dump($categories);
  //          wp_set_post_terms( $_POST['post_ID'], $categories, 'category' );


$cat_ids = array_map( 'intval', (array)$_POST['my_categories']);
$cat_ids = array_unique( $cat_ids );

//foreach ($_POST['my_categories'] as $cat) {
  //  print_r('Category: ' .  $cat . '<br>');
//}
//print_r("POST ID:" . $_POST['post_ID']);


wp_set_object_terms( $_POST['post_ID'], $cat_ids, $taxonomy);
```

Comment: What does the following says: `$result = wp_set_object_terms( $_POST['post_ID'], $cat_ids, $taxonomy); echo $result->get_error_message();`?

Answer (score 0):

I have rethought the problem:

Finally, I resolve it with save_post hook:

```
function enhanced_portfolio_categories_save_post(){

    $terminos = array();
    foreach ($_POST['my_categories'] as $key) {
        $custom_tax = get_term_by('term_id', $key, 'portfolio_categories');
        array_push($terminos, $custom_tax->term_id);
    }

    wp_set_object_terms( $_POST['post_ID'], $terminos, 'portfolio_categories');

}
```